# Show and use drag/reorder-button on UITableViewCell without being in "edit"-mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a section where I'd like to show the drag/reorder-button depending on a setting from another section. I have implemented `canMoveRowAt:` and `moveRowAt:to:`, but the tableView only shows the drag-icon when `tableView.isEditing = true`.
I also need the ability to delete rows, but I want *that* functionality to only appear in edit-mode, so simply constantly being in edit-mode isn't any good for me.

I've tried playing around with the `cell.showsReorderControl`, but this also just hides and shows the button when in Edit-mode, and doesn't affect the cell in non-Edit mode.

Is there a way to show the reorder-button when not in Edit-mode?